# How to mix drawing with and without VBOs

Tags: opengl-es-2.0

Since the OpenGL drawing calls are affected by a recently bound VBO, how do you unbind a VBO if you also want to draw vertices you have dynamically created on the spot that are not in VBO?

None of the examples I have looked at show how to disable a VBO buffer, like you would an attribute array pointer. Perhaps this is not particularly common since most applications are either going to have everything in a VBO, or nothing, perhaps mixing the two scenarios is not common.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To unbind a VBO you simply call `glBindBuffer` with second parameter set to 0.

> The value zero is reserved, but there is no default buffer object for
>   each buffer object target. Instead, buffer set to zero effectively
>   unbinds any buffer object previously bound, and restores client memory
>   usage for that buffer object target.

And then you have to bind another VBO or draw from the client memory.

Answer (score 0):

Also remember to disable your attribute pointers when mixing VBO and non-VBO. When you call:

```
GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(positionHandle);
```

It should be followed by a:

```
GLES20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(positionHandle);
```

Once you are done with drawing so that you can reenable it with your other drawing method (VBO or non-VBO).